# Unable to create Shortcut with Hotkey is Special Key using WshShell

Tags: c#, desktop, shortcut

I'm trying to assign {Num *} to a shortcut but error showed
**'Value does not fall within the expected range**"

Please help!

My Code:

```
  public static string CreateDesktopShortcut(string appPath)
        {
            object shDesktop = (object)"Desktop";
            WshShell shell = new WshShell();
            string shortcutAddress = (string)shell.SpecialFolders.Item(ref shDesktop) + @"\notepad.lnk";

//delete before creating a new one
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(shortcutAddress))
                System.IO.File.Delete(shortcutAddress);


            IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress);
            shortcut.Description = "New shortcut for a Notepad";
            shortcut.Hotkey = @"*";
            shortcut.TargetPath = appPath + @"\notepad.exe";
            shortcut.Save();
            return shortcutAddress;
        }
```